# integration: like "velocity if acceleration is a function of velocity"

Tags: integration

A variable $a$ changes over time according to:

$\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{I}{\phi}a^{\gamma}$

where $I$ and $\phi$ are constants. $\gamma<0$ is also a constant.

I now want to find out the value of $a$ at $t=1$ if I know that $a_{t=0}=a_{0}$.

With the following two sources, [Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236128/solve-for-velocity-if-acceleration-is-a-function-of-velocity) and [Link2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411761/integral-of-velocity-if-acceleration-is-a-function-of-velocity), I came up with this solution:

$a_{t}=\left[\left(\frac{I}{\phi}t+C\right)(1-\gamma)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma}}$

where the integration constant $C$ can be pinned down at $a_{0}$ such that:
$a_{1}=\left[\left(\frac{I}{\phi}+\underbrace{\frac{(a_{0})^{1-\gamma}}{(1-\gamma)}}_{C\, at\, a_{0}}\right)(1-\gamma)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma}}$

I'd be really grateful if anyone can tell me whether this is right or completely wrong?

Comment: not sure if this is relativity or unrrlated to the title.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee changed the title

Comment: but acceleration is a function of velocity namely the slope of the tangent to the change in velocity in a  velocity time diagram.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Actually, this is a problem I have in econ, ... It's just that the various "velocity/acceleration" problems on StackExchange seem to be closest to mine ... I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Broadly, this is a nonlinear, 1-dimensional first order differential equation. Many have explicit solutions, but in general they don't. As for whether that solution is correct, differentiate with respect to $t$ to see if the differential equation is satisfied. Plug in $0$ to see if you chose the right constant.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins Thanks a lot for your answer. I think $C$ is right. However, I'm not so sure about the derivative with respect to time. I get something like $\frac{da}{dt}=\frac{I}{\phi}a_{0}^{\gamma}$. But is this right if it is $a_{0}$?

Comment: If you get $a_0$ then something is wrong. This would be saying that $a(t) = \frac{I}{\phi} a_0^{\gamma} t + C$ for some constant $C$. My guess is that you substituted something incorrectly. Note that we aren't free to choose $C = a_0$, since $a_0$ is defined by $a_0 = \left[\left(\frac{I}{\phi} (0) + C\right)(1 - \gamma)\right]^{\frac{1}{1 - \gamma}}$. Indeed, $C$ will be uniquely determined by the value of $a_0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as you mentioned physics in your title, I will solve it in a physicist way, i.e I will not be much rigorous in my steps. Hopefully this will help. First of all, let us call $I/\phi = \alpha$ and, because $\gamma <0$, we can write $\gamma = -|\gamma|$. With these notations, your equation becomes:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{da}{dt} = \alpha a^{-|\gamma|} =\alpha \frac{1}{a^{|\gamma|}} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
To simplify even more my notation, I will write write $|\gamma|$ as $\gamma$ from now on. Here's where the physicist point of view takes place: write (not rigorously) equation \ref{1} as:
\begin{eqnarray}
a^{\gamma} da = \alpha dt \Rightarrow \int a^{\gamma}da = \alpha\int dt \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\gamma+1}a^{\gamma+1}= \alpha t + C \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus, from (\ref{2}) we obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
a = a(t) = \bigg{[}\bigg{(}\frac{I}{\phi}t+C\bigg{)}(\gamma+1)\bigg{]}^{\frac{1}{\gamma+1}}
\end{eqnarray}
where $C$ is completely defined by $a(t=0)$ by equation (\ref{2}).

Comment: There's nothing non-rigorous about this. Any mathematician would accept this as a proof. The only room for error is that we have to be sure $\gamma \neq -1$, since then the given antiderivative wouldn't be defined. But this isn't a problem since we've assumed (after redefining) that $\gamma > 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @CharlesHudgins you are completely right! I assumed $\gamma \neq -1$ because of his first answer, but I should have mentioned this assumption. Thanks a lot for your comment!